# 2 and only 2 characters for oracle table

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a table in oracle that will accept 2 and only 2 characters.  I tried using char(2), but if I put in 1 character in an insert statement, it will accept it.  How do I make oracle only accept any inserts of 2 exact characters and reject 1 and 3 and higher characters?  I have searched all over the internet and can't seem to find an answer for this.

Thanks!
Christopher

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a CHECK constraint that enforces this restriction

```
SQL> create table foo (
  2    col1 varchar2(2) NOT NULL
  3   ,check( length(col1) = 2 )
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 'ab' );

1 row created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1* insert into foo values( 'a' )
SQL> /
insert into foo values( 'a' )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C0022134) violated
```

Comment: +1 - very simple solution.  If you don't want to allow nulls, you will also need a not null constraint on this column too, since the check constraint will still allow for null values.  You could theoretically also update the check constraint to handle nulls as well, but a not null constraint would be more straightforward.

Comment: @Craig - Excellent point.  I added the NOT NULL constraint to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pre-insert trigger to check the length - I can't think of a way to prevent a single character.